# My Android TextView isnt visible

Tags: android

MainActivity class, is there any error in this code? Tried many methods but still doesnt work

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        double CurrencyRate;
        double a;
        double b;
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_Custom:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,CustomXchangeRate.class);
                this.startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.Convert_Currency:
                if (CurrencyTV.toString()=="AUD"){
                    CurrencyRate=0.944;
                    a=Double.parseDouble(FrTV.getText().toString());
                    b=CurrencyRate*a;
                    String c =Double.toString(b);

                    SgdTV.setText(c);


                }
```

Can seem to get my option menu Convert_Currency working?

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:title="Convert"
    android:id="@+id/Convert_Currency"
    app:showAsAction="always"
   />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_Custom"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Add custom Rates"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_Default"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Show Default Rates"/>
</menu>
```

My menu.xml full codes of it, Updated it

Comment: So basically when i press my "convert" button on the menu, its suppose to do Convert_Currency

Comment: Are you overriding following @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater(); inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); return true; }

Comment: Yes i did @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        this.myMenu=menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your if condition by this.

**It will worked**

```
if (CurrencyTV.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("AUD"))
```

Comment: @Xiu Han try this

Answer (score 1):

please try to convert your textview's text value instead of TextView.

```
if (CurrencyTV.getText().toString().equals("AUD"))// Change here
```

Comment: if you are inflating menu.xml like @john O'Reilly John said then try Dharambir Singh answer

Comment: can you post whole activity in which you are inflating menu.xml